# CakePHP model design - better way?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, data-modeling

I have a model "Goal" that has four types of children (which all have different fields):

campaign_roi
call_success
phone_skill
call_qluality

The goal table contains a field "model" which specifies one of the four models above.

But one "Goal" only has one of the 4 children. They will never have two types of children. Is there a better way than creating a model for each child? And if not, how can I dynamically specify which child type any goal is?

For instance, I want to see a goal and it's child - in this case a campaign_roi. How can I set it up where I can do this

```
$this->Goal->find('first', array(
   'conditions' => array(
      'Goal.id' => $id
   )
)
```

And it returns information from the Goal model and it's child campaign_roi?

Comment: [Creating and Destroying Associations on the Fly](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the 4 types of models hold information that can't be merged in to a single type.  That is, they have no commonality, except that they all have a goal_id and are mutually exclusive.  Let's assume that an instance of any one of these models can only belong to one goal.

You can set up your Goal model, using the belongsTo relationship, and the conditions clause, so that it will attempt to load a child of each type.

```
class Goal extends AppModel {
    /* ... */

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'CampaignRoi' => array(
            'className' => 'CampaignRoi',
            'conditions' => array('Goal.model' => 'CampaignRoi'),
            'foreignKey' => 'model_id'
        ),
        'CallSuccess' => array(
            'className' => 'CallSuccess',
            'conditions' => array('Goal.model' => 'CallSuccess'),
            'foreignKey' => 'model_id'
        ),
        'PhoneSkill' => array(
            'className' => 'PhoneSkill',
            'conditions' => array('Goal.model' => 'PhoneSkill'),
            'foreignKey' => 'model_id'
        ),
        'CallQuality' => array(
            'className' => 'CallQuality',
            'conditions' => array('Goal.model' => 'CallQuality'),
            'foreignKey' => 'model_id'
        )
    );

    /* ... */
}
```

In your goal table, you'll have the model field and a model_id field.  The model field will be populated with CampaignRoi, CallSuccess, PhoneSkill or CallQuality.  After you've done your find on Goal, you'll still need to inspect goal.model to determine what type of child you need to work with.

This is a method I've used several times, though I can't quite remember what happens with the other models.  At worst, it's an empty array or field (i.e. empty($goal['CampaignRoi']) == true, if $goal['Goal']['model'] == 'CallSuccess').

Sub-typing in relational databases is never fun.

Answer (score 0):

For model inheritance, we can create sub_table with main_table_id to point back to the main_table. But it's quite convoluted when you need to get a full record.

If that 4 fields are the only difference between the children, you can put them all in the goals table. And if they are the same data type, you can use just one field. You can write custom find methods in the model (findModel1(),...) or define an array('model1name'=>'campaign_roi',...) for easy reference later when you do find().

How you design it is really a trade-off between robustness/extensibility and convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you work it the other way around? Not from the goal point of view, but from the others?

Don't specify no relation in the Goal model, specify hasOne relation in CampaignRoi, CallSuccess, PhoneSkill and CallQuality.

Do your queries thru CampaignRoi, CallSuccess, PhoneSkill and CallQuality.